In JavaScript, how to listen to a pointerUp event from the right mouse button while the left mouse button is held down?
How to listen to pointerUp event from a different mouse button when a mouse button is pressed down?
Im trying to listen to pointerUp event from right mouse button while the left mouse button is held down. For some reason when any mouse button is held down subsequent pointer down events from any other mouse buttons are not triggering pointerUp events, is there a workaround for this issue?

why would pointer DOWN events trigger a pointer UP event?

Please [Edit] your question - click the button marked [<>] and provide  a [mcve]. Have a look at [ask].

There are (can be) multiple mouse buttons, but there is only one pointer.

Pointerup events only fire when ALL buttons are released
This is by design and why OP's code does not work.

mouseup events fire when ANY button is released.
pointerup events fire only when ALL buttons are released.

As the documentation says, "The pointerup event is fired when a pointer is no longer active."
Since the code is targeted for a mouse, the easiest solution is to fallback to using the mouseup event. This can be accomplished with a single event handler:


addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  if (e.button === 2 && e.buttons & 1) {
      console.log('do something');
   }
})


// optional 
addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => e.preventDefault());
Hold the left mouse button down and toggle the right button.



Notes:
button is what triggered the event whereas buttons is a bitwise flag with the status of all buttons. The left button flag is read using a bitwise AND.

Your answer is the only one that actually addresses the question instead of just providing an alternative solution. Thank you for explaining why the PointerUp event wouldn't work. Best answer imho

You should consider disabling the context menu if you want consistent output, if that is applicable to you:


document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    let button;
    if (event.button === 0) button = 'Left';
    else if (event.button === 2) button = 'Right';
    console.log(`Mouse Down: ${button}`);
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
    let button;
    if (event.button === 0) button = 'Left';
    else if (event.button === 2) button = 'Right';
    console.log(`Mouse Up: ${button}`);
});

// disable context menu
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});



